# Unable to add property to HTML element via jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to add a property to my input elements via this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $.each({
        "bmsw": 4, "dp": 1, "jmsw": 2, "mhsw": 4, "mp": 5, 
        "pr": 10, "prrv": 3, "sh": 2, "st": 10, "sw": 2, 
        "swrv": 1, "ud": 1
    }, function(key, value) {
        $('#' + key).prop('data-point-value', value);
    });
});
```

If I load my page and look at the source, I see my  elements with the name and id shown in the list above.  There's no data-point-value attribute set on them though.  I've tried using both prop and attr but neither of them see to add the attribute to the HTML.

What am I doing wrong?

If it matters at all, this element is down four divs, a form, a table, and a td element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I load my page and look at the source, I see my elements with the name and id shown in the list above. There's no data-point-value attribute set on them though. I've tried using both prop and attr but neither of them see to add the attribute to the HTML.

`attr` was the correct thing to use to set `data-*` attributes on the elements.

If you're using "view source" or similar to view the elements, the changes you're making client-side won't show. "View source" shows the page source as it was delivered from the server (frequently, it goes back to the server and re-retrieves the page, in fact). "View source" does **not** show you the current state of the DOM. You need to use your browser's *live* DOM viewer. In Chrome, FireBug, and IE's Dev Tools, this is usually a "DOM" tab or similar.

If you use `attr` in your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $.each({
        "bmsw": 4, "dp": 1, "jmsw": 2, "mhsw": 4, "mp": 5, 
        "pr": 10, "prrv": 3, "sh": 2, "st": 10, "sw": 2, 
        "swrv": 1, "ud": 1
    }, function(key, value) {
        $('#' + key).attr('data-point-value', value);
    });
});
```

Then the element with the `id` `"bmsw"` will get a `data-point-value` attribute with the value `"4"`, the element with the `id` `"dp"` will get the value `"1"`, and so on.

Gratuitous complete example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ejihav/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ejihav/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Setting Data Attributes</title>
  <style>
    span {
      border: 1px solid grey;
      padding: 0 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Each of the below is an element with an <code>id</code> matching its text. Click the element to see the value of its <code>data-point-value</code> attribute.</p>
  <p>
    <span id="bmsw">bmsw</span>
    <span id="dp">dp</span>
    <span id="jmsw">jmsw</span>
    <span id="mhsw">mhsw</span>
    <span id="mp">mp</span>
    <span id="pr">pr</span>
    <span id="prrv">prrv</span>
    <span id="sh">sh</span>
    <span id="st">st</span>
    <span id="sw">sw</span>
    <span id="swrv">swrv</span>
    <span id="ud">ud</span>
  </p>
  <p id="output"></p>
  <script>
    (function() {
      $(document).ready(function(e) {
          $.each({
              "bmsw": 4, "dp": 1, "jmsw": 2, "mhsw": 4, "mp": 5, 
              "pr": 10, "prrv": 3, "sh": 2, "st": 10, "sw": 2, 
              "swrv": 1, "ud": 1
          }, function(key, value) {
              $('#' + key).attr('data-point-value', value);
          });
      });

      $(document).on("click", "span", function() {
        var value = $(this).attr("data-point-value");
        $("#output").html(
          "The value of <code>" +
          this.id +
          "</code>'s <code>data-point-value</code> is <code>" +
          value +
          "</code>"
        );
      });
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for that explanation!  I switched over to viewing in IE instead of Safari and then was able to see the attribute added on via the developer section.

Comment: @Gargoyle: Good deal! Glad that helped. Safari has [dev tools](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/2SafariDeveloperTools/SafariDeveloperTools.html) too.

Answer (score 1):

use below:

```
$('#' + controlID).attr('data-controlValue', value);
```

Or,

```
$('#' + controlID).data('controlValue', value);
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('#' + key).attr('data-point-value', value);
```

here's a **DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/balexandre/uKw25/

[image]

---

while `attr` gets and sets the property element, independet of what it is, and always return a string, `prop` get's a boolean condition, for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes" checked />
```

`$(elem).prop("checked")` will return a boolean value of `true` while `$(elem).attr("checked")` will return the string `"checked"`

This is the same when setting values:

`$(elem).prop("checked", true)` will mark the checkbox as true, but to use the `attr` you need to write `$(elem).attr("checked", "checked")`.

I hope this get you a clear view why your code is not working ... as you are using `prop` but not setting any boolean value as it is expected by the method.

Comment: Note that using `data` won't actually put the information on the element itself. That may not matter (if it's only ever accessed from jQuery via `data`), but it matters if you're going to look for that information in some other way.

Comment: true, it appends to the element DOM only to be accessible for manipulation using jQuery.

Comment: *"`prop` is used to only GET the properties values, not to set their values.*" That's just not at all correct. `prop`, like `attr`, is used to set properties. Just not attributes.

Comment: @ balexandre: I **am** reading [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2): *"The .prop() method is a convenient way to set the value of properties—especially when setting multiple properties..."* It is, in fact, the **only** way to set certain properties via jQuery. Why do you think they have an entire section devoted to the "setter" version of the function? :-)

Comment: rewrote it to take any doubts in the air :) - still, after reading and using it in a current daily basis ... I'm kind'a lost as well...

Comment: @ balexandre: :-) Yeah, the `prop` and `attr` thing is a bit of a mess. :-) Note that *"Only use prop if you want to append or retrieve boolean values"* is still incorrect. You don't set, say, `selectedIndex` to a boolean value. Yes, there *are* some boolean properties, but they're not all there is. Keep it simple: You use `prop` to set *properties*, `attr` to set *attributes*, and `data` to store data in a location managed by jQuery that isn't actually on the element at all.

Comment: I get it's not true, but I can't seam to work my head (1.15am here) on why `prop` wouldn't set it, though, as a rule of thumb, I always only use `prop` to set/get boolean versions of the property value.

Comment: That still isn't working for me.  It doesn't throw an error that I can see but it just doesn't add the attribute.  I even added an alert($('#' + key).attr('name')); right before the attr set to just make sure it was finding the actual element, and it's popping up with the correct name each time.  When I look at the page source though, there's no data-point-value attribute there.